# Is it possible to implement Sql Server Fail-over Clustering on Windows Server 2008 R2 with RAID-I and RAID-V

Tags: sql-server, failover

I have performed test lab for SQL Server Fail-over clustering using the URL below

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31604.sql-server-2014-step-by-step-guide-to-setup-a-failover-cluster-virtual-lab.aspx

The URL is for Windows server 2012, I have done the same for Windows Server 2008 R2, everything working fine.

The question is in my live server HDD are on RAID, can I perform the same on live server.

In other words is it possible to implement Sql Server Fail-over Clustering on Windows Server 2008 R2 with RAID-I and RAID-V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to implement Sql Server Failover Clustering on Windows Server 2008 R2 with RAID-I and RAID-V

I have successfully implemented and tested